# How to send message from server to client using Flask-Socket IO

Tags: python, flask, flask-socketio

I'm trying to create a python app that can send message from server to client. Currently I'm using this sample code from [here](https://github.com/j2kun/flask-sockets-example). It's a chat app and it's working fine. I tried to modified the app and add a new function in the server side python code that will print a message "Dummy" into the client but seems like it didn't work.

Here's my html code:

**index.html**

```
<body>
    <ul id="messages"></ul>
    <ul id="output"></ul>
    <form action="">
      <input id="m" autocomplete="off" /><button>Send</button>
    </form>

<script src="{{url_for('static', filename='assets/vendor/socket.io.min.js')}}"></script>
<script src="{{url_for('static', filename='assets/vendor/jquery.js')}}"></script>

<script>
  var socket = io.connect('http://127.0.0.1:5000/chat');

  $('form').submit(function(){
    socket.emit('chat message', $('#m').val());
    $('#m').val('');
    return false;
  });

  socket.on('chat message', function(msg){
    $('#messages').html($('<li>').text(msg));
  });

  socket.on('output', function(msg){
    alert(msg)
    $('#messages').html($('<li>').text(msg));
  });
</script>
```

Here's my backend code:

**web_app.py**

```
from flask import Flask
from flask import render_template
from flask_socketio import SocketIO
from flask_socketio import emit

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'secret!'
socketio = SocketIO(app)
connected = False

def socket_onload(json):
    socketio.emit('output', str(json), namespace='/chat')
    print('received message: ' + str(json))


@socketio.on('chat message', namespace='/chat')
def handle_chat_message(json):
    print('received message: ' + str(json))
    emit('chat message', str(json), broadcast=True)


@socketio.on('connect')  # global namespace
def handle_connect():
    global connected
    connected = True
    print('Client connected')

@socketio.on('connect', namespace='/chat')
def handle_chat_connect():
    print('Client connected to chat namespace')
    emit('chat message', 'welcome!')

@socketio.on('disconnect', namespace='/chat')
def test_disconnect():
    print('Client disconnected')


@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')


@app.route('/blah/')
def blah():
    return render_template('blah.html')
```

**main.py**

```
import web_app
import threading
import time

def main():
    import web_app
    webapp_thread = threading.Thread(target=run_web_app)
    webapp_thread.start()
    # webapp_thread = threading.Thread(target=run_web_app, args=(i,))

    while web_app.connected==False:
        print "waiting for client to connect"
        time.sleep(1)
        pass

    print "Connected..."
    time.sleep(3)
    print "Trying to print dummy message..."
    web_app.socket_onload("Dummy")

def run_web_app():
    web_app.socketio.run(web_app.app)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I can see "received message: Dummy" in the terminal but nothing's change on the web browser.

Comment: Hard to know without having a complete example to test with. Did you look in the browser's console to see if there are any errors?

Answer (score 17):

You have **two** mistakes which prevent you from doing so:

**First**, you are trying to emit an event with socket.io outside from the socket context.

When a function is wraped with `@socketio.on` decorator, it becomes an `Event-Handlers`. 
While an event is fired on the server-side it will search for the right handler to handle the event and initialize the context to the specific client that emitted the event.

Without this context initializing, your `socketio.emit('output', str(json), namespace='/chat')` will do nothing because the server doesn't know to whom it should emit back the response.

Anyway, there is a little trick for emitting events **manually** to a **specific client** (even if you are not in its context). Each time a socket has opened, the server assign it to a "private" room with the same name as the socket id (`sid`). So in order to send a message to the client outside from the client context, you can create a list of connected client's ids and call the emit function with the `room=<id>` argument.

For example:

**web_app.py:**

```
...
from flask import Flask, request

clients = []

@socketio.on('connect')
def handle_connect():
    print('Client connected')
    clients.append(request.sid)

@socketio.on('disconnect')
def handle_disconnect():
    print('Client disconnected')
    clients.remove(request.sid)

def send_message(client_id, data):
    socketio.emit('output', data, room=client_id)
    print('sending message "{}" to client "{}".'.format(data, client_id))

...
```

Then you would probably use this as follow:

**main.py:**

```
import web_app
import threading
import time

def main():
    webapp_thread = threading.Thread(target=run_web_app)
    webapp_thread.start()

    while not web_app.clients:
        print "waiting for client to connect"
        time.sleep(1)

    print "Connected..."
    time.sleep(3)
    print "Trying to print dummy message..."
    web_app.send_message(web_app.clients[0], "Dummy")

...
```

But even if you try this, it will not work (which brings us to the second mistake).

---

**Second**, you are mixing eventlet with regular Python threads and it's not a good idea. the green threads that eventlet uses do not work well with regular threads. Instead, you should use green threads for all your threading needs.

One option which I found in the internet, is to monkey patch the Python standard library, so that threading, sockets, etc. are replaced with eventlet friendly versions. You can do this at the very top of your main.py script:

```
import eventlet
eventlet.monkey_patch()
```

After that it should work  fine (I tried it on my own). Let me know if you have another problems...

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However it still didn't work. There's also no error in console log. Just a question, what is the best way/library to implement real time  python-html update? Seems like flask-socketio doesn't have a direct way to do this. My only intention is to have a python module push the output from the other python module to html.

Comment: So I don't understand why you are trying to create a separate thread for this. Can you give me an example flow for your need? I think you can start your action from the socket.io server thread and only if you want to execute a background task use `socketio.start_background_task` function.

Comment: Sorry I am very new to flask. The reason I create a separate thread is because the line `web_app.socketio.run(web_app.app)`  was blocking further process.   
  
So currently I'm developing a user-computer 'conversation' app that will take user speech as input > transcribe it into text using Watson STT > send it to Watson Conversation Service > get response from Watson > display response in Python. This part is already done. So now, I plan to also display the input (transcribed text) and the response from Watson into a webpage (in real time)

Comment: I found the exact solution for you! Checkout "Using a Message Queue" with Socket.io (link [here](https://python-socketio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#using-a-message-queue) ). This will give you the ability to emit events to your clients from a process other than the server. I didn't try it before but it looks very powerful. Read the documentation in the link I gave you and search for more examples over the internet... Good luck! :)

Comment: Is there an better way to do than "sid" thing ? Maybe in javascript instead of flask ?

Answer (score -3):

These decorators are there for simply loading the pages `index.html` and `blah.html` these don't do anything --- don't pass any variable or don't write anything to the template they just render it, meanwhile all the things you are doing are there for the command line if you have to print or pass anything it would have to be in these functions :

```
@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')


@app.route('/blah/')
def blah():
    return render_template('blah.html')
```